# Combine multiple Excel workbooks into one

Tags: matlab, excel, concatenation, vba

Update:

Enclosed below is a sample VBA code that I found on joinedupdata.com. I need help making two modifications: (1) remove the criteria that repeated header rows are deleted and (2) see if there's a way to separate the concatenated data from each Excel file by a blank row in the combined sheet that has the filename of the following table in the left-most cell.

```
Dim firstRowHeaders As Boolean
Dim fso As Object
Dim dir As Object
Dim filename As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim s As Sheet1
Dim thisSheet As Sheet1
Dim lastUsedRow As Range
Dim file As String

On Error GoTo ErrMsg

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
firstRowHeaders = True 'Change from True to False if there are no headers in the first row

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'PLEASE NOTE: Change <<Full path to your Excel files folder>> to the path to the folder containing your Excel files to merge
Set dir = fso.Getfolder("<<Full path to your Excel files folder>>")

Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For Each filename In dir.Files
    'Open the spreadsheet in ReadOnly mode
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)

    'Copy the used range (i.e. cells with data) from the opened spreadsheet
    If firstRowHeaders And i > 0 Then 'Only include headers from the first spreadsheet
        Dim mr As Integer
        mr = wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(mr - 1).Copy
    Else
        wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    End If

     'Paste after the last used cell in the master spreadsheet
    If Application.Version < "12.0" Then 'Excel 2007 introduced more rows
        Set lastUsedRow = thisSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
    Else
        Set lastUsedRow = thisSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)
    End If

    'Only offset by 1 if there are current rows with data in them
    If thisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Or Application.CountA(thisSheet.Rows(1)) Then
        Set lastUsedRow = lastUsedRow.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    lastUsedRow.PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next filename

ThisWorkbook.Save
Set wb = Nothing

#If Mac Then
    'Do nothing. Closing workbooks fails on Mac for some reason
#Else
    'Close the workbooks except this one
    For Each filename In dir.Files
        file = Right(filename, Len(filename) - InStrRev(filename, Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
        Workbooks(file).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next filename
    #End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ErrMsg:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "There was an error. Please try again. [" & Err.Description & "]"
    End If
```

I've been trying (without much success) to find a way to merge multiple Excel spreadsheets into one. I'm using MATLAB to analyze experimental data. A dozen Excel spreadsheets go in and an equal amount come out.

**Spreadsheet Structure**:

The data in each Excel file is only on the first sheet (Sheet 1).

Each sheet has four columns of data (with headers) and a variable number of data rows underneath.

Each Excel file has a unique filename.

*Example*:

```
Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4
1111       22222      3333       4444
11122      11223      33344      33444
etc        etc        etc        etc
```

**Preferred Merging Behavior**:

1) Multiple Excel files are merged into one sheet on a single new spreadsheet.

2) Column headers are maintained during the merge.

3) Instead of adding each successive data set to the bottom of the previous one ("vertical" addition), it would be great if the columns could be placed side-by-side ("horizontal" addition) with a one-column break in-between.

4) The filename of each original file is placed into a row just above the first column header.

5) Preferably cross-platform (Windows/Mac OS X). However, if VBA with ActiveX is the only way to go, that's also fine.

*Sample Output*:

```
Filename1                                     Filename2                
Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4     Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | ...
111        22222      33333      4444         1111        222222    44444
Data...    Data...    Data...    Data...      Data...     Data...   Data...
```

Comment: You can do it with VBA, is there a specific part you are having trouble with?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Also what is the upper limit of how many Excel files you want to concatenate together? Remember that depending on what version and what extension you save you will be limited in how many columns you can have. But as long as you don't do over 3000 files you should be ok. Please include any work you have done so far. A good starting point would be to use the Macro Recorder and then go into the editor and start adapting to your needs.

Comment: I have no experience coding in VBA. Therefore, it would be great if you could point me to working code that I could then tweak. Also, I'm on a Mac: this makes running ActiveX-containing macros difficult.

Comment: @nbayly: I'm using MS Office for Mac 2011. I will need to join at most 15 files at once. I currently do not have working code as I have no VBA experience.

Comment: How will you feed your script information about what files to join (filename, directory, etc.)?

Comment: @nbayly: I will probably just have a dedicated directory into which all the excel files will be put into.

Comment: Here is a starting point for you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139724 This script will loop through all files in a folder. Then you should google how to get VBA to read a .csv file and so forth. If you have issues or errors with your code, post them here and we would be delighted to nudge you on your way. Remember that SO is not a code writing service but rather a forum to get help about specific issues. There are numerous other services out there that can write code for you for very little money.

Comment: @nbayly: Posted a VBA script into the original post. Any and all help in making those two modifications are very, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop through the workbooks in the same folder as the master workbook should suffice.

```
Sub collect_wb_data()
    Dim wbm As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim fp As String, fn As String, nc As Long

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbm = ThisWorkbook
    With wbm.Worksheets("sheet1")   'set this properly to the receiving worksheet in the master workbook

        fp = wbm.Path
        fn = "*.xl*"
        fn = Dir(fp & Chr(92) & fn)

        Do While CBool(Len(fn))
            If Not fn = .Parent.Name Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fp & Chr(92) & fn, _
                                        UpdateLinks:=False, _
                                        ReadOnly:=True)
                nc = nc + 1
                .Cells(1, nc) = Left(fn, InStr(1, fn, Chr(46)) - 1)
                wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=.Cells(2, nc)
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Set wb = Nothing
                nc = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column
            End If
            fn = Dir
        Loop

        '.parent.save   'Uncomment to save before finishing operation
    End With

    Set wbm = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Oddly, there has been scant mention of just how the list of workbooks to be processed was intended to be derived. I've used a simply file mask on the same folder that the master workbook resides in but I have left it easy to change. If specific files are to be processed, a multiple list can be made from a standard File Open dialog instead. A hard-coded array of workbook names is another option.

I've left a couple of commands (e.g. screen updating disabled, saving before finishing) commented out. You might want to uncomment these once you are satisfied with the method(s).